# setState(() {}); Required in Android Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

After selecting image using `image_picker: ^0.6.0+15` package, we received a file in Android and iOS, but the issue is with the display/render of the image in the UI.

```
//Display Image to user
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
              child: _selectedImage == null
                  ? Center(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text('No Image selected'),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Image.memory(
                      _selectedImage.readAsBytesSync(),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
            ),
          )
```

`setState(() {});` is required in Android but on iOS image display with out calling `setState(() {});` glitches the UI on iOS if we call `setState()`.

We have an option:

```
Future getImage(int sourceType) async {
    _selectedImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: sourceType == 1 ? ImageSource.gallery : ImageSource.camera,
      maxHeight: 500,
      maxWidth: 500,
    );
    // to show Images in Images  View
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

But is there any explanation on `setState()` is not needed on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Any interface should be ready for multiple `build()` calls per second. You should be free to call `setState()` with no reservations anytime. When this is a problem, you are doing something wrong.

I think this is what's wrong in your case: you call `_selectedImage.readAsBytesSync()` in `build()`. You should do that elsewhere and keep info about it in fields of your class, which the `build()` function uses to simply convert that information to UI.

Comment: As per my exp this (_selectedImage.readAsBytesSync()) will be excute when _selectedImage is not null.

Comment: It's not good you are supposed to do it. As your build function had side effects like this, you'll run into all kinds of issues.

Comment: there is no issue with this code, it's working perfectly. my point is why I am supposed to call setState() for android but on iOS image display without calling setState(() {});